# Ajax call to servlet from JavaScript from a function doesn't return value

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to load a map with markers in website. When I call the servlet from js outside the function I get the values(coordinates to display marker on), but when I put the code to call servlet in a function and then create the map, I only see a blank map with no places or marker. I'm saying it's a blank MAP because I can see the mouse pointer like a palm(like in a google map).

So, the map loads but the call to the function which calls the servlet and gets coordinates is not done. When I put the code to call the servlet outside without a function it works. I display the array of values from servlet using `console.log()`. I see only `[]`.

Maybe the `xhr.open()` is not called. Idk. I've been working in JavaScript for only few days. I dont really know how it works. Please help.

```
        function initMap() {
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        getLocation(xhr); // calling the function that gets location from servlet

        //setTimeout(function(){
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map');
        map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv);
        map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(latArray[0], lngArray[0]));
        map.setZoom(18);
        console.log(deviceId);
        console.log(latArray);

        latArray.forEach(function(lat, i) {
            // For each one create info window
            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: '<div id="content>' + '<p style="color:#000000">DeviceID:<p>' + '<p>' + deviceId[i] + '</p>' + '</div>'

            });
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(latArray[i], lngArray[i]),
                icon: "phone6.png"
            });
            //marker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(latArray[0],lngArray[0]));
            marker.addListener("click", function() {
                //infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                //marker.setMap(null);
                placeMarker(this.map,this.marker,latArray[i],lngArray[i]);
            });
        });
   // },10000);
    }


    function open(){
        xhr.open('POST', 'GetLocationFromDB', true);
        xhr.send();
    }
    //map.fitBounds(bounds);

    function getLocation(xhr) //function that gets coordinates in array from servlet
    {
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {  //when I put this code above where I created the map, it works
            if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    if (!((i + 1) % 3 == 0)) {
                        latArray.push(data[i]);
                        lngArray.push(data[i + 1]);
                        i = i + 2;
                        deviceId.push(data[deviceIdLoopCount]);
                        deviceIdLoopCount += 3;
                    }
                }  
            }

        }
    }
```

Edit:

I just read that you cant call the function `xhr.onreadystatechange` and it's only reference. I tried executing `onreadystatechange()` but it didnt work. I passed `xhr.onreadystatechange` to a variable where I called the function. How do I execute it?

Comment: I would appreciate it if you tell me the reason for downvoting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not calling `open()` and `send()` method  of `xhr`

```
function getLocation(xhr) //function that gets coordinates in array from servlet
{
    xhr.open('POST', 'GetLocationFromDB', true);
    xhr.send();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        ....
    }
}
```

Please refer [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)

EDIT 1:

define one function containing your map related thing

```
function createMap(){

    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map');
    map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv);
    map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(latArray[0], lngArray[0]));
    ..
}
```

Then call:

```
getLocation(xhr);
setTimeout(function(){ createMap() },200)
```

Comment: hi..you were right. i see the values in `console.log`. But the map is still blank

Comment: I see the values in console only the first time i'm loading. when i reload the array values are empty

Comment: that worked..but is there a way to create the map without calling the function. The reason I'm trying to put the code to get data in a separate function to separate creating map and the getting data part. I'm calling the `getLocation` on a regular interval to check if data in database has changed..maybe i can call the `createMap()` in `getLocation()` only the first time servlet is called?

Comment: i think you didnt understand...i dont want to call the `createmap()` inside `getlocation`. I dont want to reload map when i get data from database. i only need to change the marker in map

Comment: How you calling that function after interval?\

Comment: i have not done that yet..if i can create map without calling it inside `getLocation()` i will do that..

Comment: hey man..i used `setTimeout(function(){ createMap() },200)` to call `createMap()` after I called `getLocation(xhr)` and it worked. I didn't have to call `createMap()` inside `getLocation(xhr)`. thanks a lot for your help. If you edit your answer with the `setTimeout()` after `getLocation()` I will be glad to accept your answer. thanks again for your help. :)